# Wordpress вставить рекламу (РСЯ) после тега more

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такая функция, для автоматической вставки кода после тега more:

```
function adsgoolge_ssd($content) {
$google_ads='
здесь ваш рекламный код
';
$content=preg_replace('#<span.*?id="more-(.*?)".*?></span>#','<span id="more-\1"></span></p><center>'.$google_ads.'</center><p style="text-align: justify;">',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'adsgoolge_ssd');
```

Если ставить стандартный код РСЯ, который выглядит так:

```
<!-- Yandex.RTB R-A-XXX -->
<div id="yandex_rtb_R-A-XXX"></div>
<script>window.yaContextCb.push(()=>{
  Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
    renderTo: 'yandex_rtb_R-A-XXX',
    blockId: 'R-A-XXX'
  })
})</script>
```

то ломается. Ошибка

```
syntax error, unexpected 'yandex_rtb_R' (T_STRING)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как совместить РСЯ и функцию вывода после тега more?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, есть масса плагинов для подобных бесчинств. Кстати, Вам не показалось странным, что ошибка выдаёт только часть имени (yandex_rtb_R)? Вам не кажется, что Ваш скрипт, **тире** в имени он воспринимает знаком минус???

Answer (score 0):

Одинарные кавычки замените на двойные:

```
renderTo: "yandex_rtb_R-A-XXX",
```